# .NET replace LocalizedButton with an image

Tags: asp.net, .net

I inhereted this old .net 2.0 site and need to make this code view as an image, like a normal input type = "image" src=".." etc.

```
<cc1:LocalizedButton ID="btnLogin" runat="server" />
```

The site is precompiled, so I have no access to the code behind, and I need to keep this forms functionality.

It is VB to if that makes any difference.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: Code for first question: https://gist.github.com/1320856

Comment: And what is a LocalizedButton? It's not a standard control...

Comment: not sure to be honest, I stripped out all the tables and all the erroneous code with this form still working. This code that was left is in the updated section in my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`ImageButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.aspx) control

Comment: That breaks the forms functionality though.

Comment: I get this Server Error:
"""
 The base class includes the field 'btnLogin', but its type (BeehiveMedia.LanguageBroker.LocalizedButton) is not compatible with the type of control (System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton).
"""

Comment: Oh, it submits the username and password to the database, and validates it. If validated it sends them to the users homepage. So when I change the original cc1:LocalizedButton with asp:ImageButton I get a server error on page load. But it is a gray html text button, and I need to replace it with an image. I also tried attaching CSS to the button in the form of a background-image to no avail.

Comment: OK, I missed the part where you said you had no access to the code-behind... I'm afraid it's gonna be hard to maintain this site without access to its source code! If the LocalizedButton doesn't have a feature to display an image, there's nothing you can do, except perhaps fiddling with the DOM in Javascript

Comment: Yea, its very hacky intensive, and no code behind is a major annoyance. Thank you for your efforts anyhow Thomas.